# How to remove spammy search results from Google

Tags: search, search-engine, spam-prevention

Often, when I search for something, I get results like `www.<site>.com/Search/<my search terms>`, which are nothing but the exact same search repeated on `www.<site>.com` and are of no use.

How do I handle this? Can I remove these search results based on pattern or something? I wouldn't want to remove specific sites because that'd be pointless I think.